# Python 3 installed, error when running

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I installed **Python 3.5.1** on my Mac, **alongside Python 2.7.10**. When I run `python --version`, it returns `Python 2.7.10`, and when I run `python3 --version`, it returns `Python 3.5.1`, which should confirm that Python 3 correctly installed. However, whenever I try to run a command or file with **python3** in **Terminal**, it gives me this error:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system
>   codec   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/**init**.py",
>   line 123
>       raise CodecRegistryError,\
>                               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Current thread 0x00007fff72bb4000 (most recent call first): Abort
>   trap: 6 Farshids-MacBook-Pro-2:mysite Sasha$ python3 Fatal Python
>   error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/**init**.py",
>   line 123
>       raise CodecRegistryError,\
>                               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Current thread 0x00007fff72bb4000 (most recent call first): Abort
>   trap: 6

and also pops up with a message saying `"Python quit unexpectedly."` As you can see in the error, it mentions 2.7, which means that it was probably trying to run the code using 2.7.

How do I fix this? By the way, I installed Python 3 to follow a Django tutorial that does not work without Python 3, and I'm so knowledgeable about Python to be able to adjust.

Comment: If I had to guess it looks as if your py3 and py2 installations are conflicting.  Line 123 appears to me to be formatted per python3 syntax and that's why your py2 interpreter throws a syntax error.

Comment: How did you install python3?

Comment: @MikeLane from the python website. Just downloaded the installer and ran it.

Comment: @SashaAhrestani so how did you solve it?

Comment: Check what environment variables you have set. Make sure there aren't any related to Python.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably $PYTHONPATH is set to use your Python2.x. To verify this type

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

If you see path related to Python2.x, try unsetting it.

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH shows a bunch of paths. I checked my /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions folder, and found that the only folder in there was 3.5. I think Python 2 is completely gone! The PYTHONPATH has a bunch of paths with "/Versions/2.7" in them, and this folder is non-existent now. Should I replace all these paths with 3.5? I can give you a full list.

Comment: And if I would like to`unset PYTHONPATH`, would that mean I would have to `set` it too?

Comment: Did you try just removing `Versions/2.7` from *PYTHONPATH*? If you are using non-standard library than don't unset it, just remove 2.7 related path. BTW I would recommend using `virturalenv` so that you can work with multiple version of python without changing system variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the shebang line (starting with #! on the first line) as python3 (#!/usr/bin/python3.5) path if you are executing them as executables. But the errors you are getting are due to syntax incompatibility between your scripts and the python interpreter you are using. Study the changes in python3.x version and make changes in your scripts accordingly. You can have a look at [this](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html) for your reference.