# Installation of packages using pip on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

I am trying to install certain packages like pyautogui,etc. on my macOS Sierra. But it is throwing out some error.

```
$ sudo pip3 install pyobjc-core
```

The error is

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding

Current thread 0x00007fffb7f853c0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: It may be caused by an incorrect `PYTHONPATH`. Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946286/python3-installed-successfully-but-cannot-be-opened-in-terminal) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978794/python-3-installed-error-when-running)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 installed successfully, but cannot be opened in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946286/python3-installed-successfully-but-cannot-be-opened-in-terminal)

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` or rather `PYTHONHOME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something wrong with your Python installation. Anaconda have better package manager than pre-install Python.
I suggest you install Anaconda (download [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)). Choose Anaconda2 (use Python 2 for less trouble)

Then try again with pip

```
pip install pyobjc-core
```

Comment: Anaconda is not getting installed.I tried conda update anaconda. But I am still getting the same error.